# tinymce wysiwyg editor - text cursor issue, text fields/areas become inactive

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm working on a couple of features for a project that I created a few months back when I was first learning React. I wanted to add a wysiwyg editor to one of my forms so that a user could have more control with the "about" section of an event page (i.e. embed media and images, html source code editing, font formatting, etc.)

The editor that I'm using is [TinyMCE 5.0](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes50/).
This project is a Rails backend and React frontend. (I'm not using Redux - this project was a way to practice React when I first learning it.)
You can find my last commit [here](https://github.com/abeciana1/le-cine-frontend/tree/14e270aefe072df85288974f9504659b3d9f4208) if you would like to see my code

### The Problem

I'm able to get the wysiwyg editor rendered. I can also type and format text inside the editor's body. When I click on the code icon or image embed icon (like in the gif below), a new modal appears but when I click into it to type, the text cursor appears and then disappears. So I can't type and it seems that the text area and fields become inactive (for lack of a better term - I'm still somewhat in the beginning of my coding journey.)

I just signed up and TinyMCE gives access to premium plugins as well, so I don't think it's an issue with my account permissions/subscription.

I'm also not receiving anything in the console but if there's any help you can provide, it would be appreciated!

Thanks!

[TinyMCE 5 editor - text cursor issue - text areas become inactice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5jOJ.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly likely that the library you are using for your modal (that contains TinyMCE) is not allowing focus to go elsewhere.  As you have not stated the library you use for your modal I can't tell you anything about how to address this but we know this is an issue with common libraries like Bootstrap:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/#usingtinymceinabootstrapdialog

Whatever you are using should have a similar ability.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Yes, I was using react-bootstrap and I decided to remove the modals and just have a simple conditional in state to show/hide the form based on button-click or submit events.